# 1D CNN on Pytorch: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (10x3 and 10x2)

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, torch

I have a time series with sample of 500 size and 2 types of labels and want to construct a 1D CNN with pytorch on them:

```
class Simple1DCNN(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Simple1DCNN, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=50, 
                                      out_channels=20, 
                                      kernel_size=5, 
                                      stride=2)
        self.act1 = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.layer2 = torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=20, 
                                      out_channels=10, 
                                      kernel_size=1)
        
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(10* 1 * 1, 2)
    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(1, 50,-1)
        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = self.act1(x)
        x = self.layer2(x)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        
        return x

model = Simple1DCNN()
model(torch.tensor(np.random.uniform(-10, 10, 500)).float())
```

But got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so_pytorch.py", line 28, in <module>
    model(torch.tensor(np.random.uniform(-10, 10, 500)).float())
  File "/Users/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "so_pytorch.py", line 23, in forward
    x = self.fc1(x)
  File "/Users/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 93, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "/Users/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1692, in linear
    output = input.matmul(weight.t())
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (10x3 and 10x2)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shape of the output of the line `x = self.layer2(x)` (which is also the input of the next line `x = self.fc1(x)`) is `torch.Size([1, 10, 3])`.

Now from the definition of `self.fc1`, it expects the last dimension of it's input to be `10 * 1 * 1` which is `10` whereas your input has `3` hence the error.

I don't know what it is you're trying to do, but assuming what you want to do is;

1. label the entire `500` size sequence to one of two labels, the you do this.

```
# replace self.fc1 = nn.Linear(10* 1 * 1, 2) with
self.fc1 = nn.Linear(10 * 3, 2)

# replace x = self.fc1(x) with
x = x.view(1, -1)
x = self.fc1(x)
```

2. label `10` timesteps each to one of two labels, then you do this.

```
# replace self.fc1 = nn.Linear(10* 1 * 1, 2) with
self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2, 2)
```

The output shape for **1** will be (batch size, 2), and for **2** will be (batch size, 10, 2).

Answer (score 0):

The activation input x to self.fc doesn’t have the expected number of features, so you would need to change the in_features of the first nn.Linear layer in self.fc