# How to solve this error while making training file in python

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

So I have been making an A.I. program with 0 experience in coding in python just as a hobby. While making the training file, I faced an error and I am not able to solve it.

This is my Training file-

```
import numpy as np
import json
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset,DataLoader
from NeuralNetwork import bag_of_words , tokenize , stem
from Brain import NeuralNet

with open('intents.json','r') as f:
    intents = json.load(f)

all_words = []
tags = []
xy = []

for intent in intents['intents']:
    tag = intent['tag']
    tags.append(tag)

    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        w = tokenize(pattern)
        all_words.extend(w)
        xy.append((w,tag))

ignore_words = [',','?','/','.','!']
all_words = [stem(w) for w in all_words if w not in ignore_words]
all_words = sorted(set(all_words))
tags = sorted(set(tags))

x_train = []
y_train = []

for (pattern_sentence,tag) in xy:
    bag = bag_of_words(pattern_sentence,all_words)
    x_train.append(bag)
    
    label = tags.index(tag)
    y_train.append(label)

x_train = np.array(x_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)

num_epochs = 1000
batch_size = 8
learning_rate = 0.001
input_size = len(x_train[0])
hidden_size = 8
output_size = len(tags)

print("Training the model...")

class ChatDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self):
        self.n_samples = len(x_train)
        self.x_data = x_train
        self.y_data = y_train

    def __getitem__(self,index):
        return self.x_data[index],self.y_data[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.n_samples

dataset = ChatDataset()

train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset,
                            batch_size=batch_size,
                            shuffle=True,
                            num_workers=0)

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = NeuralNet(input_size,hidden_size,output_size).to(device=device)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=learning_rate)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for (words,labels) in train_loader:
        words = words.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(dtype=torch.long).to(device)
        outputs = model(words)
        loss = criterion(outputs,labels)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    if (epoch+1) % 100 == 0:
        print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {loss.item():.4f}')

print(f'Final Loss : {loss.item():.4f}')

data = {
"model_state":model.state_dict(),
"input_size":input_size,
"hidden_size":hidden_size,
"output_size":output_size,
"all_words":all_words,
"tags":tags
}

FILE = "TrainData.pth"
torch.save(data,FILE)

print(f"Training Completed, File Saved to {FILE}")
```

This is the program which contains all the layers of the neural network which I have named as Brain.py-

```
import torch.nn as nn   

class NeuralNet(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,input_size,hidden_size,num_classes):
        super(NeuralNet,self).__init__()
        self.l1 = nn.Linear(input_size,hidden_size)
        self.l2 = nn.Linear(input_size,hidden_size)
        self.l3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size,num_classes)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self,x):
        out = self.l1(x)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.l2(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.l3(out)
        return out
```

And this is the error which VSCode is sending me-

```
File "f:/Aryav files/J.A.R.V.I.S/J.A.R.V.I.S. Mark III/Train.py", line 81, in <module>
    outputs = model(words)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py", line 103, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 1848, in linear
    return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (8x8 and 15x8)
```

I am a very beginner in programming so please tell me the exact line no. and the line which I need to replace it with. Thank You

Comment: Is this the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65945996/1d-cnn-on-pytorch-mat1-and-mat2-shapes-cannot-be-multiplied-10x3-and-10x2)?

Comment: Maybe I can't tell

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html), `nn.Linear` has input size and output size as arguments.

So, in your network here:

```py
def __init__(self,input_size,hidden_size,num_classes):
    super(NeuralNet,self).__init__()
    self.l1 = nn.Linear(input_size,hidden_size)
    self.l2 = nn.Linear(input_size,hidden_size)
    self.l3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size,num_classes)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
```

`l1` takes `input_size` of features and outputs `hidden_size` of features.
`l2` also takes `input_size` of features and outputs `hidden_size` of features.
It will only work if `input_size == hidden_size`, which I think, in this case, is not the same.

What you want to achieve is to specify all the hidden layers with `hidden_size` nodes, right?
Then, a simple fix would be

```py
self.l1 = nn.Linear(input_size,hidden_size)
self.l2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size,hidden_size)
self.l3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size,num_classes)
```

Then, the inputs and outputs between layers should match.

Sidenote, I think you need another instance of `ReLU`. This is considered bad, reason is posted [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/using-same-dropout-object-for-multiple-drop-out-layers/39027/6).

Answer (score 0):

In your second layer you are putting input_size as a dimention instead of hidden_size(which is your output size of the previous layer).
Use the following lines in your model:

```
self.l1 = nn.Linear(input_size,hidden_size)
self.l2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size,hidden_size)
self.l3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size,num_classes)
```